# Is it possible to pass information (e.g. updates) from hyper-v base vm to differencing vms?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, cloning

Hi everybody (first post, so please don't kill me),

I have a hyper-v host which contains several vms (Server 2016, W10). Right now, I have to update (e.g. windows update) every single one of them. My question:

Is it possible to have a "base" installation of let's say W10 from which I create differencing disks ("children") from to use for various purposes. I would then only update the base machine and "merge" - prefereably automatic - the various children with that base machine.

I believe the linked clones of vmware/esxi have such a feature?

Do I have it all wrong and there is a better/proven way to do this?

Thank you very much and regards,
Thomas

PS: I know about performance issues etc.

Answer (score 1):

When I read your post, I thought about [differencing disks](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-differencing-disks-explained/), but you have to update each children VM further separately. But "if the parent disk is modified by some other process, all differencing disks related to it become invalid, and all data written to the differencing disks is lost." - [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc720381(v=ws.10))

So, it seems that you have to install them separately. Alternatively, you can deploy [WSUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/get-started/windows-server-update-services-wsus).